# Why does my window manager (stumpwm) show a cross on the mouse pointer when it is over the root window?

Tags: x11, mouse, cursor, twm, stumpwm

My mouse pointer turns into a cross when there are no elements under it other than the root window. I've been having this issue with [stumpwm](https://stumpwm.github.io/) since I installed it, but I know that a cross over the root window is a normal occurrence in `twm` or any other basic window manager.

Can it be removed?

Comment: What do you mean by “no element”? Do you mean if the cursor is outside of any window (i.e. on the root window)?

Comment: @Gilles yes, I meant that, just like you experience it in twm.

Answer (score 2):

insert into your .config/stumprc/config file:

(run-shell-command "xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr")

Comment: Any particular place in the file?  Can you explain what this does?